# 日本語に違和感：「このため、コミュニティの評価が低い質問が履歴に残っています。」

Tags: バグ, 討議, 翻訳, 日本語

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/question-limited

> 質問に対して、迅速で役に立ち、十分吟味された回答を受け取ることで、サイトでよい体験をしていただきたいと思っています。質問をするときは、作業の遂行に役立つような回答を探しているため少し急いでいます。このため、コミュニティの評価が低い質問が履歴に残っています。 そのため、良い質問をすることを学習するまでペースを落とすようお願いしています。

ちょっとこれだけだと文意が読めません。

原文は

> We want you to have a good experience on the site by receiving prompt, helpful vetted answers to your questions. We realize that when you come to ask questions, you're in a bit of a hurry, because you're looking for an answer to help you get your work done. This has resulted in a history of questions that have been poorly-received by our community - so we're asking you to slow down until you've learned to ask better questions.

ですので、ニュアンスとしては

> 「(前略)質問の際には、目前の作業の遂行に今すぐ役立つような回答を求めて焦りがちになるのはわかります。しかしそういった質問の数々は、コミュニティから低く評価されることになりがちです。ですので、より良い訊き方が出来るようになるまで質問のペースを少し落としてもらいたいと思います。」

といった感じだと思うのですが、これ意訳しすぎて訳文としては不適切ですよね…
もう少し逐語訳な感じで自然な日本語に直せないでしょうか

Comment: ヘルプの記事に違和感を感じたら、適切な翻訳案をコミュニティにあげて、同意したらすぐ適用します。指摘ありがとうございます！

Comment: 下記に案をだしましたが、これでいいですか？

Answer (score 2):

逐語訳にこだわるよりは、日本語話者が読んですぐ理解できるような平易な日本語であるほうが望ましいと考えます。ですので趣旨が変わらないかぎり、意訳であることはさほど気にする必要がないでしょう。メタに残っているこれまでの翻訳関係の議論を見ればわかるとおり、原文とはまるで異なる訳になっているようなものさえもあります。

それはそれとして一応以下のように私訳してみました。原文に書かれていないようなニュアンスも若干補っています。

---

#### 週に 1 件の質問しかできないと言われるのはなぜですか?

> We want you to have a good experience on the site by receiving prompt, helpful vetted answers to your questions.

私たちは常に皆さんが、十分に吟味されて役に立つ、しかも迅速な回答を得ることによって、当サイトで良質な体験を得ていただくことを望んでいます。

> We realize that when you come to ask questions, you're in a bit of a hurry, because you're looking for an answer to help you get your work done.

当サイトに質問のために訪れる方々は、作業を遂行するための助けを探しに来ているのですから、早く回答が欲しいと考えるのは至極当然のことであって、そのことはよく理解できます。

> This has resulted in a history of questions that have been poorly-received by our community - so we're asking you to slow down until you've learned to ask better questions.

しかし残念ながら、そうやって回答を急ぐあまりにコミュニティから低い評価を受けるような質問をされてしまったようです。このような場合、より良い形での質問の仕方を会得していただくまでの間は、質問のペースを落としていただくようにお願いしています。

Comment: 下記に案をだしましたが、これでいいですか？

Answer (score 0):

## 原文：

#### 週に 1 件の質問しかできないと言われるのはなぜですか?

私たちは常に皆さんが、十分に吟味されて役に立つ、しかも迅速な回答を得ることによって、当サイトで良質な体験を得ていただくことを望んでいます。当サイトに質問のために訪れる方々は、作業を遂行するための助けを探しに来ているのですから、早く回答が欲しいと考えるのは至極当然のことであって、そのことはよく理解できます。しかし残念ながら、そうやって回答を急ぐあまりにコミュニティから低い評価を受けるような質問をされてしまったようです。このような場合、より良い形での質問の仕方を会得していただくまでの間は、質問のペースを落としていただくようにお願いしています。

#### それでは、緊急の質問に対する回答はどのように得たらいいですか?

[**調べて下さい！**](/search)すでに多くの質問が投稿され、回答がついています。このような回答を見つけてそこから学ぶことは、両者の時間の節約になります。質問と回答を見つけるための[高度な検索](/help/searching)機能をよく調べる良い機会でもあり、また、追加の質問をする前に検索する方法も練習できます。

#### このブロックを解除するか、週に質問できる件数を増やすようにリクエストできますか?

**申し訳ありませんが、これらの制限は手動での解除や変更はできません。弊社にお問い合わせいただいても何もできません。**[できる限り最良のガイド](/help/how-to-ask)を提示いたしました。考えを変えてコミュニティの一員になることを希望していただいて幸いですが、アカウントから週に 1件を超える質問を受け付けるには、もう少し確立されたメンバーになっていただく必要があります。

**アカウントを削除したり複数のアカウントを作成したりしても役に立ちません。**これらの制限を回避しようとすると、相当の期間サイトを**まったく**使用できなくなるリスクがあり、同僚によるこのサイトの使用が大きな危険にさらされます。すこし努力してよい回答をすることで、ほんの数日でこのブロックを解除できます。その他の方法で回避しようとしないでください。

---

## 案：

#### 週に 1 件の質問しかできないと言われるのはなぜですか?

質問に対して、迅速で役に立ち、十分吟味された回答を受け取ることで、サイトでよい体験をしていただきたいと思っています。質問をするときは、作業の遂行に役立つような回答を探しているため少し急いでいます。**このため、コミュニティの評価が低い質問が履歴に残っています。** そのため、良い質問をすることを学習するまでペースを落とすようお願いしています。

#### それでは、緊急の質問に対する回答はどのように得たらいいですか?

[**調べて下さい！**](/search)すでに多くの質問が投稿され、回答がついています。このような回答を見つけてそこから学ぶことは、両者の時間の節約になります。質問と回答を見つけるための[高度な検索](/help/searching)機能をよく調べる良い機会でもあり、また、追加の質問をする前に検索する方法も練習できます。

#### このブロックを解除するか、週に質問できる件数を増やすようにリクエストできますか?

**申し訳ありませんが、これらの制限は手動での解除や変更はできません。弊社にお問い合わせいただいても何もできません。**[できる限り最良のガイド](/help/how-to-ask)を提示いたしました。考えを変えてコミュニティの一員になることを希望していただいて幸いですが、アカウントから週に 1件を超える質問を受け付けるには、もう少し確立されたメンバーになっていただく必要があります。

**アカウントを削除したり複数のアカウントを作成したりしても役に立ちません。**これらの制限を回避しようとすると、相当の期間サイトを**まったく**使用できなくなるリスクがあり、同僚によるこのサイトの使用が大きな危険にさらされます。すこし努力してよい回答をすることで、ほんの数日でこのブロックを解除できます。その他の方法で回避しようとしないでください。

Comment: 「原文」と「案」は逆ですよね？ 「原文」と「修正案」と書いていただく方がよりわかりやすいかと思います。それはそれとして、原文で太字で強調されていた箇所に該当する部分（そうやって回答を急ぐあまりにコミュニティから低い評価を受けるような質問をされてしまったようです。）を、修正案でも太字にしておいた方が良いように思います。